# Spring AMQP and JSON Web Signature

Tags: json, spring-amqp

I have a project with Spring AMQP in which I use messages with JSON format. Now we want some of those messages to be signed using JSON Web Signature (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515), and I have several doubts:

What would be the most standard way to do this? What is the best library for signing JSON submissions? And what would also be the most standard way to publish JSON (POJO classes)?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you have to take a look to this: https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying the library https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home and it seems to work fine, but I'll also try the one you recommend.
Any thoughts on the last question? The best way to publish an API in JSON format?